# How to insert NSString * between two NSString *

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to ask an NSString * question. I have a NSString * object. The content is like the following example. (like the CSV file)

Example: (my file is longer than this one so much)

```
First Name,Last Name,Middle Name,Phone,Chan,Tim,Man,123-456-789,Tom,,,987-654-321
```

(if it is empty, no space between the ',')

How can I insert the "(null)" NSString * / or NSString * object between the two ',' by using the objective C?

```
// After convent

First Name,Last Name,Middle Name,Phone,Chan,Tim,Man,123-456-789,Tom,(null),(null),987-654-321
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the method [**`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`**](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:) (*untested*):

```
NSString *newString = [oldString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@",," 
                                                           withString:@",(null),"];
```

This might be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner in Objective-C and I didn't test this answer, but I think it does the job.

```
//given your NSString called string
NSArray *pieces = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray: [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];

NSMutableString *final = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

for(int i; i < [pieces count]; i++)
{
    if(i > 0)
        [final appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@","]];

    if([pieces objectAtIndex: [NSNumber numberWithInt: i]] == nil)
    {
        [final appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(null)"]];
    }
    else
    {
        [final appendString: [pieces objectAtIndex: [NSNumber numberWithInt: i]]];
    }
}
```

I hope I didn't screw it up too bad :)